# Como contar y llamar a otra clase de ArrayList en JAVA

Tags: java, poo, javafx, java-8, atributos

Mi duda es la siguiente. Para hacer un contador en este caso para los que no tienen asignada la  dirección seria de esta forma:

Clase `Directorio`:

```
    public int contarPerdidos() {
    int contar = 0;

    Contacto contact = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < contactos.size(); i++) {
        contact = contactos.get(i);
        if (contact.getDireccion() == null) {
            contar++;

        }

    }

    return contar;
    }
```

Clase `Contacto`

```
package com.cmc.entidades;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Contacto {

// Atributos
private String cedula;
private String nombre;
private String apellido;
private Direccion direccion;
private ArrayList<Telefono> telefonos;

// Metodos

public void agregarTelefono(Telefono telefono) {

    telefonos.add(telefono);
}

public void mostrarTelefonos() {
    Telefono telf = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < telefonos.size(); i++) {
        telf = telefonos.get(i);
        if (telf.getEstado().equals("C")) {
            System.out.println(telf.getTipo() + " - " + telf.getNombre());
        }
    }
}

public ArrayList<Telefono> recuperarIncorrectos() {
    ArrayList<Telefono> resultado = new ArrayList<Telefono>();

    Telefono telf = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < telefonos.size(); i++) {
        telf = telefonos.get(i);
        if (telf.getEstado().equals("E")) {
            resultado.add(telf);
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}

// Constructor
public Contacto(String cedula, String nombre, String apellido) {
    super();
    telefonos = new ArrayList<Telefono>();
    this.cedula = cedula;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;

}

public void imprimir() {

    System.out.println("****" + nombre + " " + apellido + "*******");
    if (this.getDireccion() != null) {
        System.out.println(
                "Direccion: " + this.direccion.getCallePrincipal() + " y " + this.direccion.getCalleSecundaria());
    } else {
        System.out.println("No tienne asociada una direccion");
    }
}

// Getters && Setters

public String getCedula() {
    return cedula;
}

public void setCedula(String cedula) {
    this.cedula = cedula;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public Direccion getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(Direccion direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public ArrayList<Telefono> getTelefonos() {
    return telefonos;
}

public void setTelefonos(ArrayList<Telefono> telefonos) {
    this.telefonos = telefonos;
}

}
```

Necesito hacer este proceso, pero la diferencia es que debo contar los estados según el criterio de otra clase llamada `Telefono`:

```
package com.cmc.entidades;

public class Telefono {

// Atributos
private String nombre;
private String tipo;
private String estado;


// Constructor
public Telefono(String nombre, String tipo) {

    if (nombre != null && tipo != null) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        if (this.tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("Movil") && this.nombre.length() == 10
                || this.tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("Convencional") && this.nombre.length() == 7)
            this.estado = "C";
        else
            this.estado = "E";
    } else {
        this.estado = "E";
    }
    
    

}



// Getters & Setters

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public String getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

}
```

En Contacto tengo el atributo de `private ArrayList<Telefono> telefonos;`

Mi duda es como llamo yo a ese ArrayList para poder hacer el método en la clase `Directorio` para el metodo `contarFijos` según el estado? No quiero que me lo resuelvan. necesito una guía. He buscado información pero no logro dar con el paro. y pienso que es algo sencillo de hacer ya que solo debo saber bien como llamar a la clase para pasarle la condición.

Comment: Agrega la clase Contacto por favor.

Comment: Ya la he agregado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo que deseas:

> En Contacto tengo el atributo de private `ArrayList<Telefono> telefonos;`
> Mi duda es como llamo yo a ese ArrayList para poder hacer el método en
> la clase Directorio para el metodo contarFijos según el estado?

En la clase `Contacto` puedes cambiar a `static` la variable y el mètodo:

```
private static ArrayList<Telefono> telefonos;
...
...
public static ArrayList<Telefono> getTelefonos() {
    return telefonos;
}
```

De esta forma el  mètodo `getTelefonos()` lo puedes llamar en cualquier otra clase para obtener los telèfonos:

```
 ArrayList<Telefono> telefonos = Contacto.getTelefonos();
```

Comment: Que locura hombre, claro ahora entiendo mucho mejor la lógica del porque no pasaba. Te pasaste, muchas gracias por tu colaboración mi código funciono a la perfección.

Comment: Excelente @Kafira , saludos